# Remove spacing around lstlisting in beamer blocks

Tags: beamer, listings, vertical-spacing

Consider the lstlisting in this MWE. (I have added normal text and itemize environment blocks for comparison.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
%\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
%\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
%\topsep 0pt
%\parsep 0pt
%\itemsep 0pt
%\partopsep 0pt
\lstset{aboveskip=0pt, belowskip=0pt}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Title}
    \begin{block}{Block}
%       \vspace{-0.85ex}
        \begin{lstlisting}
some text
some more text
        \end{lstlisting}    
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{Block}
        some text\\
        some more text
        \mbox{}
    \end{block}

    \begin{block}{Block}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item some text
            \item some more text
        \end{itemize}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The listing comes with supplementary vertical spacing above and below, compared to the other two blocks. I tried setting various lengths (see code commented out), but this had no visible effect.

How can I suppress this vertical spacing, without using `vspace`, if reasonably easy? If not easy, I’d prefer using a `vspace` than use complicated and fragile code to modify the inner workings of `lstlisting`, but is it then at least possible to use a symbolic name for the space to be suppressed instead of a constant that has to be manually adjusted by trial-and-error (e.g., `\vspace{-\thenameofsomelength}` rather than `\vspace{-0.85ex}`)?

Related (but different): [spacing within block and between blocks with list in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276985/); [How to modify itemize vertical spacing within blocks in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94066/); [Why such spurious vertical space before listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351434/) (related to tikz overlays); [Spacing inside listings in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446927/); [Extra vertical glue in listings within beamer frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510509/) (closest to my question, but talks about glue, I’m not sure this space really is glue, and the answer only refers to `aboveskip` and `belowskip`, which I used).

Comment: I think the cause is, `lstlisting` adds `\strut` to every line of its output (so they share the same height with normal input). You can test with `\begin{block}{Block}  \strut some text\\  \strut some more text  \end{block}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ interesting! And do you know how I can remove exactly the space added by this `\strut`?

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice but you can try `\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\setbox\strutbox\hbox{}]` (since `\strut` simply uses box `\strutbox`). Here `\ttfamily` is optional.